# Excel convert table formula on column range to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have multiple columns in Excel (`Field1` to `Field7`) that I am checking for an empty string in any of those fields. I am using the following formula successfully in a cell.

```
=IF(OR(tblName[@[Field1]:[Field7]]=""),"yes","no")
```

I would like to convert this formula to VBA without putting the formula in a cell. That way the formula and calculation are not displayed to an end user.

I am using the following code to successfully convert columns to uppercase in a single line (I am using variables in my code).

```
Sheets("Data").ListObjects("tblName").ListColumns("Field1").DataBodyRange.Value = Evaluate("INDEX(Upper(tblName[Field1]),,)")
```

But when I try on a range of columns, I cannot seem to get the code right. I have tried the following (and more) unsuccessfully in an `EVALUATE` statement.

```
colVariable.DataBodyRange.Value = Evaluate("IF(OR(tblName[@[Field1]:tblName[Field7]]=""""),""yes"",""no"")")

colVariable.DataBodyRange.Value = Evaluate("IF(OR(tblName[Field1]:tblName[Field7]=""""),""yes"",""no"")")

colVariable.DataBodyRange.Value = Evaluate("IF(OR(INDEX(tblName[Field1],,):INDEX(tblName[Field7],,)=""""),""yes"",""no"")")

colVariable.DataBodyRange.Value = Evaluate("INDEX(IF(OR(INDEX(tblName[Field1],,):INDEX(tblName[Field7],,)=""""),""yes"",""no""),,)")

colVariable.DataBodyRange.Value = Evaluate("INDEX(IF(OR(tblName[Field1]:tblName[Field7]=""""),""yes"",""no""),,)")
```

Will `EVALUATE` work with what I want to do here? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You need to update your post to provide clarity and clarify any and all limitations you have for acceptable solution. Not often to see 2 working solutions to error be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of counting blanks, you can use the existing function `COUNTA()` which counts non-blanks. To avoid using `Evaluate` I opted to define the relevant variables, drop the formula into the table, and then use a value transfer to remove the formula from the worksheet.

- `tbl` - Refers to Table Object (*Update table name as needed*)
- `rng` - Refers to a Range in **first** row of data in the table. This code assumes that the columns you want to test for completeness will always be the first 7 columns.

  - If the number of columns being tested *(n)* changes, the `Resize` should be updated to `(1, n)`
  - If the starting column *(n)* of range being tested changes, the `DataBodyRange` should be updated to `(1, n)`
- `col` - Refers to the column where the completeness output will be.

  - This variable is dynamic & will always be the column immediately after your test range *(`rng`)*

I tend to avoid `Evaluate` since it has various gOtCha limitations. In this case, the issue seems to be that your formula has an array (`OR([range]) = ""`). If you update your formula to test each column individually, your formula will work but the below seems more efficient (easier to follow, less work to update in future). Example of your formula in non-array form only testing 2 cells that works:

```
Evaluate("IF(OR(tblName[@[Field1]= """", tblName[Field7]]=""""),""yes"",""no"")")
```

---

```
Sub Try()

Dim tbl As ListObject:       Set tbl = ListObjects("Table1")
Dim rng As Range:            Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange(1, 1).Resize(1, 7)
Dim col As ListColumn:       Set col = tbl.ListColumns(rng.Columns.Count + 1)

col.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF(COUNTA(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ") < 7, ""yes"", ""no"")"
col.DataBodyRange.Value = col.DataBodyRange.Value

Debug.Print "Never forgot what urdearboy did for you."

End Sub
```

---

** ***mY 2 cEnTs*** **

Unless you have an explicit reason to work with "yes" and "no" flags, I always recommend to use Boolean responses (`TRUE` / `FALSE`) which are recognized keywords in both VBA and Excel. Using Boolean output will simplify **this** formula and downstream formulas as well.

Your main goal is to test the range completeness. So just simplify formula down to that test.(`IF( [what I really care about], "yes", "no")`). With that being said, I prefer:

```
col.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=COUNTA(" & rng.Address(0, 0) & ") < 7"
```

Comment: WHAT AN OVER KILL ANSWER. DONT JUDGE ME SCOTTCRANER AND BIGBEN AND THAT OTHER GUY.

Comment: I asked this question in this manner because I want to stick with the `OR` statement because I have other fields that have different criteria (maybe using an `AND` or some other logic). So solving the `OR` issue for column ranges will allow me to apply this functionality elsewhere. I also would like to concatenate the results of this formula to an existing column dynamically. So I want to avoid using a formula in a cell. I guess if I can add the columns to an *array* manually and then apply the logic to the array and  get the results out of it, then I can apply it to the resulting column.

Comment: Not sure why the middle steps matter here when the end result is the criteria. I guess the answer you were looking for is that your formula approach won’t work because of the array. You have 2 solutions that act as a workaround to your problem. Any reason for the insistence of using evaluate? You can apply this solution using any formula you’d like without having to worry about EVALUATE limitations….

Comment: “I asked the question in this manner” you also asked if there’s another way to do this. Update your question. If 2 solutions that work aren’t what you are looking then it’s probably result of a bad question/post. There 0 reason you can’t expand on this to include additional logic.

Comment: You are absolutely right. My apologies for my nonsense responses in these comments and thank you for keeping me straight. Sometimes you need people like this in your life and you need to be willing to admit your mistake. I will review the answers again and in more depth and identify the one that works best for me based on the original question that I asked. I just need some more time to go through them further!

Answer (score 1):

### Have Range Rows Blanks?

[image]

**Usage**

```vb
Sub GetHaveRangeRowsBlanksTEST()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("tblName[[Field1]:[Field7]]")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range("tblName[Variable]")
    
    drg.Value = GetHaveRangeRowsBlanks(srg, "Yes", "No")
    
End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a 2D one-based single-column variant array
'               containing true/false values indicating
'               whether a cell of the rows of a range is blank.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetHaveRangeRowsBlanks( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal AnswerYes As Variant = True, _
    Optional ByVal AnswerNo As Variant = False) _
As Variant
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim sData():
    If rCount * cCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        sData = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            If Len(CStr(sData(r, c))) = 0 Then Exit For
        Next c
        dData(r, 1) = IIf(c > cCount, AnswerNo, AnswerYes)
    Next r
    
    GetHaveRangeRowsBlanks = dData

End Function
```

### Initial Answer (Wrong Functionality)

### Are Range Rows Blank?

[image]

**Usage**

```vb
Sub GetAreRangeRowsBlankTEST()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Data")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("tblName[[Field1]:[Field7]]")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range("tblName[Variable]")
    
    drg.Value = GetAreRangeRowsBlank(srg, "Yes", "No")
    
End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a 2D one-based single-column variant array
'               containing true/false values indicating
'               whether rows of a range are blank.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetAreRangeRowsBlank( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal AnswerYes As Variant = True, _
    Optional ByVal AnswerNo As Variant = False) _
As Variant
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim sData():
    If rCount * cCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        sData = rg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            If Len(CStr(sData(r, c))) > 0 Then Exit For
        Next c
        dData(r, 1) = IIf(c > cCount, AnswerYes, AnswerNo)
    Next r
    
    GetAreRangeRowsBlank = dData

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I find that when iterating over columns and rows, Excel really slows down. I was hoping to stick with a native function to (1) reduce the amount of code and (2) take advantage of native Excel functionality and apply logic to the whole column at once. I have to do multiple bits of logic like this throughout my code and thus I think that iterating like this would decrease overall efficiency. Is my thought process off on this?

Comment: IMO, *reducing the amount of code* is a poor reason. The efficiency of this code should be similar if not better than any *Evaluate* version. Why don't you test it? If you compare both versions (the correct and wrong) of the code, you will notice that there are only two differences (`=` vs `<>`, and the answers are switched) which should indicate how easy it is to switch from one functionality to another (similar one).

Comment: I have written code in the past that has applied iterative logic and produced poor results. Yes, it could have been how I was coding but it is not too far off from what you have proposed. I will review this again and see if I can get it to work for me. Again, thank you for taking the time out to put this together.

Comment: Not sure why you asked if there’s another way to do this if you are not open to alternative approaches. Optimizing for code LENGTH should not be a priority over readability, functionality, and performance. How many rows are in your dataset? Since you are using a table format, I assume your data is nowhere near large enough for a efficient loop (as provided in this solution) so since you are here asking others to volunteer their time on your post you should at least try.

Comment: Again, you are right. My apologies. I do appreciate the time from people to respond. It helps to solve my original problem & add to my knowledge base. The volume of data is variable; could be 100 records and I have seen end users use up to 3000 records. In the past, I was using logic to iterate over `RANGES` to read and write to cells. The performance was very poor & that shows my lack of knowledge. Since posting this question, I have moved the logic to use an array to hold the data in memory, apply the logic in the array, then insert the data back to the cells. Takes a fraction of the time.